# Converting numbers to words in Arabic

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [recursive function.. won’t work again SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040702/recursive-function-wont-work-again-sql)

I created a table containing numbers between 0 and 99;
for the numbers between these two numbers the query is working,
and it's working for these numbers too:
100, 200, 1000, 2000, 1100, 2100, 1000000. In general it works for the numbers >100 and doesn't contain a number from the table that I already created..
and for all the other numbers I get 'null'.
I think the problem is in the variable @Units but I can't focus on that anymore.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Nb as BIGINT) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR(1024)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Millions as int
DECLARE @Remainder as int
DECLARE @Thousands as bigint
DECLARE @Hundreds as int
DECLARE @Units as int
DECLARE @word as nvarchar (1024)
DECLARE @result as nvarchar(1024)

set @Millions = @Nb/1000000
set @Units = @Nb %1000000
IF @Millions > 0
BEGIN
    if @Millions = 1
        set @result = N' مليون'

    if @Units > 0 
    begin
        set @Thousands = @Units / 1000
        set @Units = @Units % 1000

        if @Thousands > 0
        begin
            if @Thousands = 1
                set @result = @result + N' و' + N'ألف'
            else
            if @Thousands = 2
                set @result = @result + N' و' + N'ألفان'
            else
            if @Thousands between 100 and 199
            BEGIN
                set @Hundreds = @Thousands / 100
                set @Remainder = @Thousands % 100
                if @Remainder = 0
                begin
            set @result = @result + N' مائة ألف'
                    set @Thousands = 0
                end
                else
                if @Remainder > 0
                begin
                    set @result = @result + N' و' +  N'مائة'
                    if @Remainder > 0 
                        set @result = @result + N' و' + dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Remainder) + N' ألف'
                end
            END
            else
            if @Thousands between 200 and 299
            BEGIN
                set @Hundreds = @Thousands / 100
                set @Remainder = @Thousands % 100
                if @Remainder = 0
                begin
                    set @result = @result + N' و' + N' مئتان ألف'
                    set @Thousands = 0
                end
                else
                if @Remainder > 0
                begin
                    set @result = @result + N' و' + N' مئتان'
                    if @Remainder > 0 
                        set @result = @result + N' و' + dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Remainder) + N' ألف'
                end
            END
            else
            if @Thousands > 299
            BEGIN
                set @Hundreds = @Thousands / 100
                set @Remainder = @Thousands % 100
                if @Remainder = 0
                begin
                    set @result = @result + N' و' + dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Hundreds) + N' مائة ألف'

                end
                else
                begin
                    set @result = @result + N' و' + dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Hundreds) +  N' مائة' 

                    if @Remainder > 0
                        set @result = @result + N' و' + dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Remainder)+ N' ألف'

                end     
            END 
            else
            if @Thousands between 3 and 99
                set @result = @result + N' و' + dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Thousands) + N' ألف'

        END 
        if @Units > 0
        Begin
            set @Hundreds = @Units / 100
            set @Units = @Units % 100
            if @Hundreds > 0 
            BEGIN
                if @Hundreds = 1
                    set @result = @result + N' و' + N' مائة'
                else
                if @Hundreds = 2
                    set @result = @result + N' و' + N' مئتان'
                else
                    set @result = @result + N' و' + dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Hundreds) + N' مائة'
            END
            if @Units > 0 
                set @result = @result + N' و' + dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Units)                            
        End

    end
END
ELSE
IF @Millions = 0 
BEGIN
    set @Thousands = @Units /1000
    set @Units = @Units %1000

    IF @Thousands > 0
    BEGIN
        if @Thousands = 1
            set @result = N' ألف'
        else
        if @Thousands = 2
            set @result = N' ألفان'
        else
        if @Thousands between 100 and 199
        BEGIN
            set @Hundreds = @Thousands / 100
            set @Remainder = @Thousands % 100
            if @Remainder = 0
                set @result = N' مائة ألف'
            else
            if @Remainder > 0
            begin
                set @result = N' مائة'
                if @Remainder > 0 
                    set @result = @result + N' و' + dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Remainder) + N' ألف'
            end
        END
        else
        if @Thousands between 200 and 299
        BEGIN
            set @Hundreds = @Thousands / 100
            set @Remainder = @Thousands % 100
            if @Remainder = 0
            begin
                set @result = N' مئتان ألف'
            end
            else
            if @Remainder > 0
            begin
                set @result = N' مئتان'
                if @Remainder > 0 
                    set @result = @result + N' و' + dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Remainder) + N' ألف'
            end
        END
        else

        if @Thousands > 299
            BEGIN
                set @Hundreds = @Thousands / 100
                set @Remainder = @Thousands % 100
                if @Remainder = 0
                begin
                    set @result = dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Hundreds) + N' مائة ألف'
                end
                else
                begin
                    set @result = dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Hundreds) + N'         مائة'         
                    if @Remainder > 0
                        set @result = @result + N' و' + dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Remainder) + N' ألف'

                end
            END 
        else
            set @result = dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Thousands) + N' ألف' 
        if @Units <> 0 
        BEGIN
            set @Hundreds = @Units / 100

            set @Units = @Units % 100
            if @Hundreds > 0
            BEGIN
                if @Hundreds = 1
                    set @result = @result + N' و' + N' مائة'
                else
                if @Hundreds = 2
                    set @result = @result + N' و' + N' مئتان'
                else
                    set @result = @result + N' و' +  dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Hundreds) + N' مائة'
            END
            if @Units > 0 
                set @result = @result + N' و' +  dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Units)
        END
    END
END

ELSE

IF @Thousands = 0
BEGIN
    set @Hundreds = @Units / 100
    set @Units = @Units % 100
    if @Hundreds > 0 
    BEGIN
        if @Hundreds = 1
            set @result = N' مائة'
        else
        if @Hundreds = 2
            set @result = N' مئتان'
        else
            set @result = dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Hundreds) + N' مائة'

        if @Units > 0 
            set @result = @result + N' و' + dbo.fnIntegerToWords(@Units)
    END
else
    set @result = (select COALESCE(word,'') from number where @Units=number)
END

RETURN @result
END
```

Comment: [Don't re-post your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040702/recursive-function-wont-work-again-sql). If you continue to do this, you'll likely find yourself banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow. Is that what you want?

Comment: why ?? im trying to know where's my fault i spend more than 24hours on that and it was working i'm trying to find someone that can see the error that im not seeing..

Comment: Because duplicate questions are highly frowned upon in the Stack Exchange network of sites, that's why. The duplication of questions necessarily implies duplication of the efforts of those reading, commenting on, and answering said questions. Why do you wish to unnecessarily increase the amount of effort spent by others?

Comment: I'm sorry but i didn't know how to ask this question before and now my question is blocked.. I'm just trying to get some help from the persons that have time to help.. I gave a big effort on that thing and I didn't wanted to just threw it ..
and it's the first time that I use this site.. I just didn't mean to bother anyone..

Comment: It's not blocked, it's closed. Closed questions are still editable, and closures can be reversed.

Comment: Ok thank You..  sorry for bothering you

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you are appending onto `result`, without initializing it.  A NULL string is not an empty string (in most databases).

Try changing the declaration to:

```
DECLARE @result as nvarchar(1024) = ''
```

Or, if you are using an older version of SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @result as nvarchar(1024);
SET @result = = ''
```

Comment: It didn't work.. but i'm gona check it further 
I really appreciate your help.. Thank You